# Can't convert project to swift 2

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I've spent several hours trying to solve these two errors that I get when trying to convert my swift 1.2 project to swift 2.  I have tried a variety of answers that I came across involving duplicate certificates, bitcode settings, compiler optimization level's etc.  I'm still having no luck converting my project.   Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1
ditto: can't get real path for source '/Users/tracepomplun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/joann-abcfteuqtvsfmjbkykjrgrttcxsq/Build/Intermediates/SwiftMigration/joann/Intermediates/joann.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/joann.build/Objects-normal/i386/joann-Swift.h'
Command /usr/bin/ditto failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you manage to make it work? I just spent 2 days migrating 100+KLOC to Swift 2.1.1 and can't archive anymore because of this (building works just fine)